# The browser's back button and events

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I have a multi-page jquery mobile html document.

One page has a link to an external page.

When I hit the back button, its not showing how the page looked when the link was clicked.

I do not know if its with the way I dynamically get the data, or its a problem with the lists.  When it goes back to the page, what events are fired?

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate to a page that is not on the same domain then a whole page load occurs on the new page and you cannot have the state of the previous page persist when the user navigates back unless you are saving the state of the page in `cookies`/`localStorage`/`sessionStorage` and restoring the state by yourself.

That being said, you can still rebuild your pages on the `pagecreate` or `pageinit` events which will fire if the user presses the back button and the pages are re-requested from the server.

If your external HTML document is on the same domain then you can just enable page caching for the page(s) you want to persist by adding the `data-dom-cache="true"` attribute: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-cache.html

Example:

```
<div data-dom-cache="true" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">...</div>
    <div data-role="content">...</div>
    <div data-role="footer">...</div>
</div>
```

In jQuery Mobile 1.0 pages are automatically removed from the DOM once you navigate away from them. Setting the `data-dom-cache` data-attribute will stop this from occurring.